# TreeTable by HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css, treetable

Stumbled upon a problem with TreeTable...
Help to understand, how to make the second level and further down will not appear when the upper td input is checked. Unfortunately I can use only HTML+CSS. [how it looks like now on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selcet/vA2eV/)

```
<table class="table-tree" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="folder2">Folder 1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="folder2" />
                <table class="table-wrapper">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="file"><a href="">Subfile 1</a></td>
                        <td class="file"><a href="">Subfile 2</a></td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="folder3">Subfolder 1</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="folder3" />
                            <table class="table-wrapper">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="file"><a href="">Subsubfile 1</a></td>
                                    <td class="file"><a href="">Subsubfile 2</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

It would be great if layout was like this

[image]

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for : http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu    , don't use <td> ,<tr> or <table> rather use <li>   <ol>  this will help you to understand and control the tree more easily

Comment: Is there a reason why your are using tables and not `ul/li`?

Comment: You all are right!!!
But if I must use only table, tr and td instead ol and ul with li?
Is it a way to do this with table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS has two errors.

First, you should select unchecked checkbox like this:

```
input:not(:checked)
```

and not relying on a fallback in rules application.

Second and more important, the rule `td input:checked + table > tbody td` is wrong.

Infact, if you have your outer checkbox checked but the nested one unchecked, that rule will still match nested table td because the first part `td input:checked + table > tbody` matches the outer table body and then the second part `td` looks for td that have that body as **ancestor**.

You should check for direct children instead.

Summing up, you can change your css to something like this:

```
*, html {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body, form, ul, li, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/**
 * Tree Table CSS
**/

.table-tree {
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
}

td {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

td label {
    background: url(http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/css-tree/folder-horizontal.png) 15px 1px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 37px;
    width: 100%;
}

td input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    top: 0;
}
// CHANGED HERE
td input:not(:checked) + table {
    background: url(http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/css-tree/toggle-small-expand.png) -3px -1px no-repeat;
    margin: -0.938em 0 0 0;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
}

td input:checked + table {
    background: url(http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/css-tree/toggle-small.png) 41px 4px no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -44px;
    padding: 1.25em 0 0 80px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

td.file {
    margin-left: -1px !important;
}
// CHANGED HERE
td input:not(:checked) + table > tbody > tr > td {
    display: none;
    margin-left: -14px !important;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
// CHANGED HERE
td input:checked + table > tbody > tr > td {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0.125em;
}
// CHANGED HERE
td input:checked + table > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 0.063em; /* 1px */
}
```

Always use the most specific CSS rule you can because when HTML gets huge you can have some surprises.

Comment: Your answer is working! :)

I made some changes and that's [what we have now](http://jsfiddle.net/selcet/tfb6M/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `table` by `ul` (or `ol`) and `td` by `li` (remove `tr`) in *HTML* and *CSS* and it will look like the disered layout on your image.

An other reason to do this is that the content you are displaying is not tabular data, it is a list of files so you shouldn't use tables but list type layout.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vA2eV/5/)**

*HTML:*

```
<ul class="table-tree" cellspacing="0">
    <li>
        <label for="folder2">Folder 1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="folder2" />
        <ul class="table-wrapper">
            <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 1</a>

            </li>
            <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 2</a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="folder3">Subfolder 1</label>
                <input type="checkbox" id="folder3" />
                <ul class="table-wrapper">
                    <li class="file"><a href="">Subsubfile 1</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="file"><a href="">Subsubfile 2</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*CSS:*

```
*, html {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body, form, ul, li, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
/**
 * Tree Table CSS
**/
 .table-tree {
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 0 0 30px;
}
li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
li label {
    background: url(http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/css-tree/folder-horizontal.png) 15px 1px no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding-left: 37px;
    width: 100%;
}
li input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    top: 0;
}
li input + ul {
    background: url(http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/css-tree/toggle-small-expand.png) -3px -1px no-repeat;
    margin: -0.938em 0 0 0;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
}
li input:checked + ul {
    background: url(http://www.webmasters.by/images/articles/css-tree/toggle-small.png) 41px 4px no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin: -1.25em 0 0 -44px;
    padding: 1.25em 0 0 80px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
li.file {
    margin-left: -1px !important;
}
li input + ul > li {
    display: none;
    margin-left: -14px !important;
    padding-left: 1px;
}
li input:checked + ul > li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 0.125em;
}
li input:checked + ul > li:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 0.063em;
    /* 1px */
}
```

Comment: You all are right!!!
But if I must use only table, tr and td instead ol and ul with li?
Is it a way to do this with table ?

Comment: it is going to be a hasle to keep tables... ul/li would be so much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I hope my example helped you [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ntbaJ)

```
<ol class="tree">
        <li>
            <label for="folder1">Folder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" checked disabled id="folder1" /> 
            <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="document.html.pdf">File 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subfolder1">Subfolder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder1" /> 
                    <ol>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Filey 1</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="subsubfolder1">Subfolder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subsubfolder1" /> 
                            <ol>
                                <li class="file"><a href="">File 1</a></li>
                                <li>
                                    <label for="subsubfolder2">Subfolder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subsubfolder2" /> 
                                    <ol>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 1</a></li>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 2</a></li>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 3</a></li>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 4</a></li>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 5</a></li>
                                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 6</a></li>
                                    </ol>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                        </li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">File 3</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">File 4</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">File 5</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">File 6</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="folder2">Folder 2</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder2" /> 
            <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="">File 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subfolder2">Subfolder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder2" /> 
                    <ol>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 1</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 2</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 3</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 4</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 5</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 6</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="folder3">Folder 3</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder3" /> 
            <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="">File 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subfolder3">Subfolder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder3" /> 
                    <ol>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 1</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 2</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 3</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 4</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 5</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 6</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="folder4">Folder 4</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder4" /> 
            <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="">File 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subfolder4">Subfolder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder4" /> 
                    <ol>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 1</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 2</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 3</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 4</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 5</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 6</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="folder5">Folder 5</label> <input type="checkbox" id="folder5" /> 
            <ol>
                <li class="file"><a href="">File 1</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="subfolder5">Subfolder 1</label> <input type="checkbox" id="subfolder5" /> 
                    <ol>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 1</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 2</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 3</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 4</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 5</a></li>
                        <li class="file"><a href="">Subfile 6</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer.
But, Unfortunately I can use only table with tr and td. ((

Comment: I understand, but still thought that my answer will help